# Visual Studio 2015 Solution tfs build with code analysis takes forever

Tags: tfsbuild, visual-studio-2015

I am building a Visual Studio 2015 Solution in TFS 2012 Build Server. The build runs fine when i disable the code analysis. When i enable the code analysis the build takes forever and does not complete. Any suggestions?

Comment: It seems to be that one of the project in the solution takes forever for code analysis. I ran code analysis in the command line for the project and found that fxcopcmd is hanging at the following point 
TypeSymbols in AssemblyUnit: System.Security.
TypeSymbols in AssemblyUnit: System.Configuration.
TypeSymbols in AssemblyUnit: System.EnterpriseServices.
TypeSymbols in AssemblyUnit: Microsoft.CSharp.
TypeSymbols in AssemblyUnit: System.Data.SqlXml.
TypeSymbols in AssemblyUnit: System.ServiceModel.Internals.
TypeSymbols in AssemblyUnit: SMDiagnostics.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug in the code analysis.
It is reported on [MS Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1604400):